# Would a carbamate be attacked twice by an alkyl lithium cuprate reagent?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

For example, say you react ethyl carbamate with methyl-$\ce{LiCu}$; would two methyl groups displace both the amide and the ester, creating an isopropyl alcohol?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so, carbonyls don't typically react with Gilman's reagent (dimethyllithium cuprate) unless the carbonyl happens to be $\ce{{\alpha}-{\beta} }$ unsaturated. So I would expect no reaction under normal reaction conditions.

Comment: Wouldn't it at least attack once to remove the ethanol group? Because, I know that a Gilman's reagent attacks carboxyl derivatives, such as esters, acetyl chlorides, and amides, but it only does so twice. That's why I was asking if GR would attack twice on a disubstituted acyl derivative.

Comment: I don't think so.  I know it reacts with acid chlorides and a,b-unsaturated carbonyls, but maybe under special conditions it will react with other carbonyl compounds.